# How to login and stay logged in using Basic Authentication for Iphone app into a rails server?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, post, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTP library to send the requests.I send the login in synchronously and then all other requests Asynchronously. My Login seems to work as does the GET method. BUT, my Post method does not work. it returns a Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=3 "Authentication needed". I created the rails server using scaffolding and then added in Devise framework. I have absolutely no clue why the GET method works fine but my post method doesnt.

If i do this in a browser however, it works fine. Can someone please help me out? I can give you all the code you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];    
[request setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
[request setUsername:kHTTP_BASIC_AUTHORISE_USERNAME];
[request setPassword:kHTTP_BASIC_AUTHORISE_PASSWORD];
```